# Add to Context Menu

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

So I'm trying to make a little Python script that will extract all items out of a folder into its parent directory. The script works fine but I want to add it to the context menu so whenever I right click a folder, it gets listed.

I followed [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/) but I had a few problems:

1. Only works on files, not folders.
2. I get a "This app can't run on your PC" error (probably because of Win10)

Along with those problems, how can I add it to its own section in the context menu?

Comment: Have a look at the answers from this SE question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders - it appears the registry key in the guide you have followed is linking to files. If you remove the "Background" level then this targets directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**for your first problem:**

Make sure you add the key to the right parent:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` when you want to right click on a folder
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` when you want to right click in the folder window

if you want to add a context entry for files, it's a bit more complicated. You normally add it for specific file-types (specific extensions).
If you want to add it for every type, there's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*`

**for your second problem:**

You need to run the python application with your script as an argument. (and then probably `"%1"` for the file you right clicked on as a second argument) If you start your script by double clicking it or by typing it into a command-window, the system looks for the python application and runs it with your script as an argument.

So this is what you need to put into the registry key: `c:\path\to\your\python.exe c:\path\to\yourScript.py "%1"`